# How do I redirect the users who aren't logged in when they go to the /user page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, authentication

I'm working on a Drupal project where a custom module is used to redirect users to another domain for authentication and I wanted to have the /user page redirect to this outside authentication server if the user is not logged in. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture the condition in hook_init by taking the login status with user_is_anonymous() and then by the 1st query argument of 'user'.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function mycustommodule_init() {
  // if 1st argument is user, and they are not logged in, send them away
  if (user_is_anonymous() && arg(0) == 'user') {
    drupal_goto('http://example.com/login');
  }
}
```

If you were able to authenticate behind the scenes with PHP, you could also make the login seemless by using hook_user with the 'login' operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could use some combination of the `rules` module and `actions` and `triggers` configuration.

When the user is on page /user and they are not logged in redirect to x.

Answer (score 1):

As examples of modules implementing external authentication, you could look at [openid.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--openid--openid.module/6), and [http_auth_ext.module](http://drupalcode.org/project/http_auth_ext.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/http_auth_ext.module).
OpenID uses [user_external_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_external_load/6), which probably requires to use [user_external_login_register()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_external_login_register/6).
External HTTP authentication uses [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_init/6).

```
function http_auth_ext_init() {
  global $user;
  // Call authentication on any page if it has not been already completed
  if (! $user->uid && ! $_COOKIE['http_auth_ext_complete']) {
    http_auth_ext_login($_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']);
  }
}
```